# how to show Api response after login in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I successfully got responses from my API, when a user login with his/her correct or incorrect credentials. how can I display those Api responses in my app whether the user put correct /incorrect name, password?

**Here is my API response if he put his correct credentials:** if he put the wrong credentials the `status code` will be `0`

[image]

***Suppose I want to print Status and Message.*** how can I display that in my app?

Here is my function to call Api:

```
  Future<void> login() async {
var jsonResponse = null;

if (passwordontroller.text.isNotEmpty && emailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
  List user;
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://kokokokokokoklogin"),
      body: ({
        'LoginId': emailController.text,
        'Password': passwordontroller.text
      }));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
    print(response.body);
    print(jsonResponse);
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Second()));
  } else {
    print("Wronggooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
    print(response.body);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid credentials")));
  }
} else {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Blank field is not allowed")));
}
```

}

And here is my textFormField where user will put his/her credentials

```
 TextFormField(
            controller:
                emailController, //==========================================
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Email",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller:
                passwordontroller, //=========================================
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Password",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.password)),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 45,
          ),
          OutlinedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () {
                login();
              },
```

SecondPage
[image]

Comment: You mean how can you access "Status" and "Message" from the `response`? Do you need it where you have the `print` statements in your code?

Comment: Yeah, exactly but maybe in the secondPage(I added the code snippet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your response to JSON and get the parts like this, add error handling (for example if JSON conversion fails):

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

And where you get the response:

```
final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
final status = jsonResponse["Status"];
final message = jsonResponse["Message"];
```

If you want to use this in `secondPage`, create a named route with arguments and pass it to the route, like explained in the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments). Or even better, use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to build the widget that needs the response. This way you can also display a progress indicator while login request is being processed.

Comment: Now, should I just need to do print like this `child: column(children: Text(status))]` ? if I want to print on the same page.

Comment: In Flutter you can get this done with a Stateful Widget and a FutureBuilder, because the value of `status` is only available after the fetch is complete. Check example [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and try to adjust your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally** Manage to solve it
Here what I did

```
class AfterLoginResPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final ApiResponse rresponse;
  const AfterLoginResPage({required this.rresponse});

  @override
  _AfterLoginResPageState createState() => _AfterLoginResPageState();
}

class _AfterLoginResPageState extends State<AfterLoginResPage> {
  var responseRef;
  //  _SecondState(this.responseRef);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tuhin = Text("Status: ${widget.rresponse.status}");
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("Status: ${widget.rresponse.status}"),
              Text("Message: ${widget.rresponse.message}"),
              Text("Name: ${widget.rresponse.userData!.name}"),
              Text("encUserId: ${widget.rresponse.userData!.encUserId}"),
              // Text("name: ${widget.UserData.name}"),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),

              OutlinedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Home(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.exit_to_app,
                    size: 18,
                  ),
                  label: Text("GoTo Home")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```